# Highlight the parent row of the selected detail row in a kendo hierarchical grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Mostly, I would like to know how to obtain a handle on the parent row once I click on a child row in the detail grid.

I have a code sample here, the end goal being to highlight the parent row if a child row is checked:

```
$("#gridMasterInfo").delegate('tbody>tr .childcheckbox', 'click', function (e) {    
    var parentcheckbox = $(this).closest("tbody>tr");
    var parentrow = $(this).closest("tbody").next().find("tr");  // Tried this, but no go.  What here?
    var childrow = $(this).closest("tr");     

    if (childrow.hasClass('k-state-selected')) {        
        childrow.removeClass("k-state-selected");         
    } else {                
        childrow.addClass("k-state-selected");
        parentrow.addClass("k-state-selected");
}
```

})

Here's my css:

```
.childcheckbox, .parentcheckbox {}
```

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid is using the `k-detail-row` and `k-master-row` classes, so this should select the parent row in your click handler:

```
var parentRow = $(this).closest(".k-detail-row").prev(".k-master-row");
$(parentRow).addClass(".k-state-selected");
```

Comment: you rock, Lars.  Thanks!